# XCode 4: Removing top-level folder

Tags: xcode4

I accidentally added a folder to the top-level of the workspace as it is displayed in XCode 4.  That is, the folder now sits right along side my project at the top-level, and I'd like to remove it but I don't see how.  The delete option is disabled when I try.  I read somewhere that after creating a workspace that such a folder is possible to delete.  I'd like to try to avoid this for the time being.

Is the meta-data for this folder stored in the project.pbxproj file?  I need to check in the changes I've made to project.pbxproj file but not the meta-data for the top-level folder I'm trying to remove.

Thanks.

Comment: locate in Finder then remove it there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had this issue. To fix it I manually removed the section relating to my unwanted group from the *project.xcworkspace* file in my *.xcodeproj* package:

1. In Finder, right click on your *.xcodeproj* package and click *Show Package Contents*.
2. Open the *project.xcworkspace* file in your favourite text editor.
3. Completely remove the xml element named 'Group' for the group you want to remove. I had to remove the following (my group was called New Group):

   ```
    <Group location = "container:" name = "New Group"> </Group>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is Xcode specific (mine is 6) but in my case it was required to make one more step in addition to Stefan's answer:

1. Right click on **.xcodeproj** in Finder -> Show Package Contents.
2. The same for **project.xcworkspace** inside: right click -> Show Package Contents.
3. After that open **contents.xcworkspacedata** with text editor (default TextEdit is ok)
4. Remove the  tag:

   ```
   <Group location = "container:" name = "New Group"> ... </Group>
   ```